# Python Standard Out

Tags: python, stdout

I'm using Hive to do a concatenate of some data into a string, group the records, and then transform using a Python Routine. It looks like Python is adding an escape character to the quoted data. I have tried using both print and sys.stdout.write. What am I doing wrong?

Example after running through Python Code Below:
Before:

```
'XML_1.0 Routing ReplyToQMgr="InfoA" ReplyToQ="Data..."
```

After

```
'XML_1.0 Routing ReplyToQMgr=\"InfoA\" ReplyToQ=\"Data...\"
```

Here's the relevant code:

```
def sort_tup(list_input):
    new = sorted(list_input)
    str = ''
    for i in range(0, len(new)):
        str = str + new[i][30:]
    return str

for line in sys.stdin:
    if line > 1:
            line = line[2:-3]
            line = line.split('","')
            strng = sort_tup(line)
            strng = strng.rstrip(' \t\r\n\0')
            strng = strng.replace('""','"')
            strng = strng.replace('\"', '"')
            strng = strng.replace("\'", "'")
            id = str(line)
            id = id[11:31]
            partition = str(line)
            partition = partition[6:10]
            strng = '%s \t %s \t %s' %(partition, id, strng)
            sys.stdout.write(strng + '\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like your `stng.replace('\"', '"')` line isn't doing what you imagine it is. `\` is an escape character in all python strings, so it's instead escaping the double quote and replacing all double quotes (`"`) with themselves.

Try this instead:

```
strng = strng.replace(r'\"', '"')
```

the `r""` notation creates a raw string, which will treat all text inside as literal. As a better example:

```
"\n"  # one character newline
r"\n" # two characters \ and n
```